# How to automatically execute stored procedures in a particular sequence, or use an SSIS package to execute stored procedures?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures, ssis, business-intelligence

I have created 2 stored procedures that need to be executed in a specific sequence.

I just do not know how to do this. I also want to do it automatically everyday with GETDATE() as the parameters to both procedures.

Is there an SSIS package I can create to execute these two procedures in the proper sequence for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to [create a job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190268%28v=sql.100%29.aspx), make each procedure call a [step within the job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187910%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) and then run the job on a [defined schedule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191439%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a SSIS package that will include 2 Execute SQL Task with a precedence constraint between them with something like `exec [MyStoredProcedure] @MyParam = GetDate();` as the sql command to execute.

Comment: I'll try this out as well. See which of the two methods is easier, I'll accept the one I end up using. Thank you!